# How many ways can we split a number into k unequal summands?

Tags: algorithm

I am taking a challenge online and came across this question, where I need to find the number of ways to split a number 'n' into 'k' unequal summands. For example,

3 - Can be split into 2 and 1.
4 - Can be split into 3 and 1. Note: We cannot do 2 and 2 because, they are equal
5 - (3,2) and (4,1). and so on..

Is there any algorithm for this.

Comment: Here's one:  list all combinations of k numbers between 1 and n; filter out the ones with duplicates, and the ones that don't sum to n. The number of items left is the answer you seek. That's a very inefficient algorithm but it's an algorithm.  Can you come up with a better one?  (Hint: k unequal summands is equivalent to k *monotone decreasing* summands. This suggests a natural recursion. Can you devise an algorithm given this hint?

Comment: This is sequence [A008289](https://oeis.org/A008289), the number of partitions of `n` into `k` distinct parts. You can compute it using recurrence relations or generating functions.

Answer (score 0):

Code in python:

```
def minArgument(x):
    s = 0
    i = 1
    while s < x:
        s += i
        i += 1
    return i - 1

def maxArgument(x):
    return x - 1

def number_of_sumsDP(M, K):
    lowerLimit = minArgument(M)
    if K < lowerLimit:
        return 0
    else:
        if K - 1 >= M // 2:
            return 1 + number_of_sumsDP(M, K - 1)
        else:
            return 0


def number_of_sums_simple(n):
    if n % 2 == 0:
        return n // 2 - 1
    else:
        return n // 2

for i in range(2, 100):
    if number_of_sumsDP(i, maxArgument(i)) != number_of_sums_simple(i):
        print("mistake")
print("works")
```

First thought dynamic programming (number_of_sumsDP(M, K)) - number of sums is equal to number of sums with the biggest possible number (subject - 1) and sums without it (with obvious stop when number is less than min arg - it doesn't make sense to add up to 10 with numbers less than 4 [minArgument] and when we start repeating ourself [if K - 1 < M // 2]).
After few prints it leads to even simpler and much efficient algorithm:
number_of_sums_simple - return division in integers by 2 when odd and the same minus one when even; as a proof I convinced myself that it works.